Autofill and matching text in options field in Angular
I am creating an input field which is autocompleting the remaining part of text inside the input field and also showing suggestions below the input field in select options. Now I want that while typing in input field I should see the relevant option as highlighted. For reference, I want exactly like (kendo suggestions) https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/combobox/suggestions/
I tried putting value in mat-select but it is not working
https://i.sstatic.net/FysUDn6V.png
